# Merging unconnected line segments using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, generalization

I am looking for a way to connect line segments that are unconnected. It is a shapefile for a network of rivers and all the lines are slightly disconnected.

Is there something like aggregate polygons but for lines?

**Edit**
My river data is not continuous but I would like it to be so I can run simplification tools on it for a generalized map. 
[image]

The lines don't always touch so when I try to generalize, it doesn't work. I want to connect the line together automatically.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is the Snap GP tool but it would be better if you can give a more elaborated description of the problem encountered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Geometric Network based on your hydro feature class, as described in this [Esri tutorial](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/geodatabases/exercise-5-building-a-geometric-network.htm).  If you want to go a quicker route, use the Create Geometric Network tool - for this you will need to have created a spatially referenced Feature Dataset (stored in a geodatabase of some kind), within which you will save the Network.

When you go through the options to create the Network, you can set the "Snap Tolerance" to a distance value specifying the max distance where gaps will be snapped together.  Obviously, the input feature class will be your hydro features.

When it is created, you can re-create with different snapping tolerance using Rebuild Geometric Network if necessary, but you can either convert back to a new feature class or else simply display the Geometric Network on your map, with no added generalization necessary.